# "at" command on Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-9.10, scheduled-tasks, at

I want to list using the "at" command.

I try this:

```
pedro@Pedro-PC:~$ ls -l | at 10:27
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 5 at Tue Apr 20 10:27:00 2010
```

But doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Your current attempt runs the command (***ls -l***) and passes the resulting list of files to ***at***.  This doesn't work, because a list of files isn't a list of commands.  You need to use ***echo***.

```
user@host:~$ echo "ls -l" | at 10:27
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 1 at Tue Apr 20 10:27:00 2010
```

You could also forget the pipe (and the quotes too):

```
user@host:~$ at 10:27 ls -l
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 2 at Tue Apr 20 10:27:00 2010
```

The output will be mailed to you (at your local user account) after it runs.

Answer (score 0):

Check your local mail (you can use `alpine`) to see any error output from your job.